# How to send a custom java class object as response to a ajax call in java servlet and retrieve it back in javascript?

Tags: java, ajax, json, class, servlets

I have a java class as follows.

```
Class GrosBean{
    private Map<Integer,String> ItemList;
    private ArrayList<String> selectItemList;

    public Map<Integer, String> getItemList() {
        return ItemList;
    }
    public void setItemList(Map<Integer, String> ItemList) {
        this.ItemList = ItemList;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getSelectItemList() {
        return selectItemList;
    }
    public void setSelectItemList(ArrayList<String> selectItemList) {
        this.selectItemList = selectItemList;
    }

}
```

I make a call to a servlet using ajax and this respective servlet fetches data from database and put into object of above class. Finally I have object of above GrosBean filled with data in it.

I want to send this data back to calling page javascript code.

I want to retrieve back this object in javascript and construct list of check boxes with the values in this object.

How do I send the java class object as ajax response using json and iterate through its list and map properties in javascript?

Please guide me in this friends.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would use a library to serialize Java -> JSON, for example [`google-gson`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), although there are other libraries that could be used instead.

Comment: @andyb Thanks firend for you reply. I too used the same library but I am unknown or may be confuse while sending a custom class object which has Map and Arraylist variable in it as ajax response and retrieve it back. I want guidance in this. I had send a normal Arraylist of normal class object as ajax response but not a class object which has Arraylist object and Map object.

Comment: `ArrayList` implements `toString` and the JSON library will try to serialize the `Map` contents by iteration, inspecting the key and value types and attempting to call `toString` on them. This process is recursive through all the class fields, resulting in the final JSON object. So as long as each field can be serialized the whole object should serialize to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) mapper to serialize your java object as a json String.

```
public String toJson(GrosBean bean) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  return mapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
}
```

alternatively using [gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/Home), the same would be achieved using below code

```
public String toJson(GrosBean bean) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  return gson.toJson(bean);
}
```

then on javascript side you can read the json like this:

```
var bean = eval(json);

bean.selectItemList.each(function(item) {
  // do something with the item
});

var itemList = bean.ItemList;
for (var key in itemList) {
  if (itemList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var value = itemList[key];
    // do something with key/value
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Friend for your reply. jackson mapper is cool thing. But I have used google library in my project every where so I thought to use only this library throughout. Can you please expalain me the same using google gson library?1

Comment: sure, it is almost the same